# Toggling Element Display/Visisbilty using Media Queries

Tags: html, css

Im building a responsive website and I have two versions of the logo. One for Mobile screen sizes and another for tablet/computer screen sizes.
Im trying to have the site toggle between the two using media queries.

I basically put two logos on divs right on top of each other, then using media queries,im having the computer size logo set to display:None when window is less than or equal to 450px. Then I set the mobile logo with the same query except i made it so that if the screen is greater than or equal to 450px its set to display:none.

**  .cover is the computer/larger logo. **

```
HTML:

<div id="paralax0">
<div class="cover" style="padding-top:25vh;">
    <img style="width:600px;" src="./img/cover.png">
</div>
<div class="covermobile">
    <img style="width:300px;" src="./img/logo8.png">
</div>
<div class="coverlinks">
    <div class "icon" style="padding: 0px 20px 70px 20px;"><a class="link" href="#"><img src="./img/resume.png"></a></div>
    <div class "icon" style="padding: 0px 20px 70px 20px;"><a class="link" href="#"><img src="./img/mywork.png"></a></div>
</div>
</div>



CSS:

.cover{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.covermobile{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 450px){
.cover{
  display: none;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 450px){
.covermobile{
  display:none;
 }
}
```

what I was desiring/expecting would happen was that screens widths <= 450px makes the larger logo disappear leaving only the mobile logo. Vise versa that screen widths >= 450px will make the mobile logo disappear leaving only the larger logo.

Instead the larger logo stays visible regardless of the screen size

Comment: Hi Jay, I've worked this out on https://jsfiddle.net/7L1k4mxo/3/ but there it seems to work for me. So I'm not quite getting your problem.

Comment: Sorry my bad, It works. I wasn't making the viewport small enough. Chrome only goes so small. when i moved it to another browser that could shrink more I could see it work, Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing your code and everything works perfectly. I think you are missing this meta tag inside your html head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, It works. I wasnt making the viewport small enough. Chrome only goes so small. when i moved it to another browser that could shrink more I could see it work, Thanks anyway!